# Two balls moving according to the same rules, but starting from different spots

Tags: javascript

I am trying to adapt the code from this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Move_the_ball It applies to the movement/bouncing from the walls of one ball. 
I would like adapt the code so it controls movement of two balls, but I struggle to set the starting point for each ball within 30px horizontally from each other and to have them moving independently. Here's where I got stuck:

```
var x = canvas.width -220;
var y = canvas.height -250;
//updating x&y position
var dx = 0.5;
var dy = 0.5;

var ballRadius = 10;

function blueBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,260,0.9)";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function greenBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    blueBall();
    greenBall();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    if(x+dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
        dx = -dx
    }
    if(y+dy > canvas.height-ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
        dy = -dy
    }
}
setInterval(draw,10)
```

My idea was to add two more variables and add conditions with new variables accordingly, but this makes the code long, especially if I want to add other balls. Is there a way to solve the problem by adding another function, or passing parameters somehow, so I could avoid repeating conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLASSES! \o/

The ideal case whenever you have entities that differ by data but share behaviour. This is just a rewrite of your code, I haven't tried it, so it probably has a couple of bugs. I also took the liberty of exchanging `setTimeout` with `requestAnimationFrame`, which is a better choice for drawing stuff.

```
class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, dx, dy, r, colour) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.colour = colour;
  }

  update(canvas) {
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
    if(this.x+this.dx > canvas.width-this.r || this.x + this.dx < this.r) {
        this.dx = -this.dx
    }
    if(this.y+this.dy > canvas.height-this.r || this.y + this.dy < this.r) {
        this.dy = -this.dy
    }
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

let balls = [
  new Ball(canvas.width - 220, canvas.height - 250, 0.5, 0.5, 10, "rgba(0,0,260,0.9)"),
  new Ball(100, 100, 0.5, -0.5, 10, "green"),
];

function tick() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  balls.forEach(ball => {
    ball.update();
    ball.draw();
  })
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

Comment: Thanks, Amadan. I tried to find the bugs, but I cannot make it working. Here is the code after my changers: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lgh0q4m/30/  What am I missing here?

Comment: well.. long way before me. Answer accepted and thx again. Trying to make the code a bit more comprehensible for me I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects. Maybe sb will also find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You need separate variables for `x, y, dx, dy` for each ball in order to track them independently.
Move the calculations from the `draw()` function to a new function and pass the aforementioned variables as parameters.
That will give you a head start. After you have it working then you can think of how to improve it further.

Comment: thanks. how to pass the variable as parameters? should I do that through a Ball function, or throug newly created function with calculations from the draw()?

Comment: @Drzemlik To the newly created function. The current ball functions are good for now.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am still struggling here: https://jsfiddle.net/Drzemlik/r4zw9hpj/88/  I tried to pass variables as parameters for only one function. The ball is visible, but not moving, what I am doing wrong here?